# Postgres get rows which hasnt match in other table

Tags: postgresql

I need your help. I need an advanced Query to my database. Im showing part of my database following:

```
Place (id, name, address)
Local (id, place_id, name)
PlaceReservation(id, local_id, date)
Media_Place (id, place_id, type)
```

Now I need a query, which gets all places with logo, which have AT LEAST ONE local which hasn't been reserved on a specific day e.g: 2015-07-01.

Help me please, because I haven't an idea how to do it. I thought about an `outer join` but I don't know how use it.

I was trying by:

```
$query = 'SELECT DISTINC *, 
                 (SELECT sum(po.rating)/count(po.id)
                  FROM "Place_Opinion" po
                  WHERE po.place_id = p.id AND po.deleted = false) AS rating,
                 mp.path as logo_path
          FROM "Place" p
          INNER JOIN "Media_Place" mp ON mp.place_id = p.id
          JOIN Local ON Local.place_id = Place.id
          LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT id AS rr, local_id
            FROM PlaceReservation
            WHERE date_start = \'2015-07-01\') Reserved ON Reserved.local_id = Local.id
          WHERE mp.type = ' . Model_Row_MediaPlace::LOGO_TYPE . ' 
          AND mp.deleted = false 
          AND p.deleted = false 
          AND rr IS NULL';
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for things that do not exist in a database is usually very inefficient. But you can change the logic around by finding places that do have a booking for the specified date, then `LEFT JOIN` that to all places with a logo and filter out the records with a reservation:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*, po.rating, mp.path as logo_path
FROM "Place" p
JOIN "Media_Place" mp ON mp.place_id = p.id AND mp.deleted = false AND mp.type = ?
JOIN Local ON Local.place_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id AS rr, local_id
  FROM PlaceReservation
  WHERE date_start = '2015-07-01') reserved ON reserved.local_id = Local.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT place_id, avg(rating) AS rating
  FROM "Place_Opinion"
  WHERE deleted = false
  GROUP BY place_id) po ON po.place_id = p.id
WHERE p.deleted = false 
AND reserved.rr IS NULL;
```

The average rating per places is calculated in a separate sub-query. The error you had was because you referenced the "Place" table (`p.id`) before it was defined. For simple columns you can do that, but for sub-queries you can't.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i didn't show my oryginal database first time, but example. I changed it in my first post now. I was trying with Your query, but it's not works. Can You look it again PLEASE?

Comment: See updated answer. The `?` is a placeholder for the type of logo in your specific framework; you can replace that for your specific framework syntax.